# How to present longitude and latitude in Blender?

Tags: export

Trying to export .csv file to open it later in Mapbox but I get an error

*Input failed. Latitude and longitude fields not present.*

How to anable latitude and longitude in Blender?

Comment: You'll have to tell us the data you're starting with, on which lat. and long. are measured

Comment: Hi Robin. First of all I have this builiding image created in Blender. And now I'd like to place it on a map . In order to do this I should...? And here is the problem 'to do what' - change it to .csv, .geojson? Have know idea :(